# jQuery chosen change display after selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

How would I be able to display Category and sub-category like this "Category subCategory" when someone selects the multiselect option? Code is like this.

**HTML :**

```
<select multiple="multiple" class="choosen-multiselect">
    <optgroup label="BLUES">
        <option value="1">Acoustic</option>
        <option value="2">Electric</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="R&B/SOUL">
        <option value="50">Contemporary R&B</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

---

**SCRIPT :**

```
$('select.choosen-multiselect').chosen({});
```

---

so, what I like to do is whenever someone selects say "Acoustic", I need to be able to display "Blues Acoustic" within the select box that jQuery chosen provides. Right now it is displaying only the selected Sub-category "Acoustic" when selected.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the parent child this way ...

```
 $('.choosen-multiselect').on('change', function ()
     {
         var selected = $(this.options[this.selectedIndex]); 
         var parent = selected.closest('optgroup').prop('label');
         var child = selected.prop('label');
         alert(parent +" "+child);
      });
```

Comment: not exactly what I want. Your code doesn't work in context of jQuery chosen.